# How to perform actions on current window in keybindings?

Tags: xmonad

In the ManageHook I can define what should happen to windows that have specific xprops etc.
For example, I can call `doShift` or `doFloat`.

How can I do the same to the currently focused window with a key binding?

The section looks like this:

```
`additionalKeys` ( [  -- Key bindings --
    -- Minimize window
      ((myModMask .|. shiftMask, xK_m     ), withFocused minimizeWindow)
```

As you can see, I can call the [minimizedWindow](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Layout-Minimize.html) function (which takes a `Window` as parameter) on the current window when pressing a combination of keys, but `doFloat` etc. do not work like this.

Comment: What does the minimizeWindow function do? Because there is really no such thing as 'minimize' in XMonad.

Comment: You are right, this function comes from `xmonad-contrib`: http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Layout-Minimize.html